# How to prevent NSWindow from closing on the windowWillClose method?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

How can I prevent my NSWindow from being closed when the `windowWillClose` method is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. By the time `windowWillClose:` is called, it is too late. You need to stop it before this point with `windowShouldClose:`.

Comment: duhh.. what a fail man. thank you so much, I didn't think about that

Answer (score 0):

Swift example:

You need to set the delegate of the `NSWindow` and implement `NSWindowDelegate`

```
func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
     return false
}
```